# In a Pandas column comparison from CSV, to blank columns are returned as not equal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have two CSV files which both contain two identifiers and I am attempting to look for discrepancies in the data.

My process so far is:
 - Read Csv files into a dataframe
 - Merge the files on the known "good" identifier
 - Check for unequal values in the known "problematic" identifier

The "problematic" identifier should be a number, however, since it was manually entered by people, this is not always the case - so I am treating both as a string for comparison.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#Read the CRM files with the identifiers as strings (by not doing this one file reads as a string the other reads as a float by default)
NEW_CRM = pd.read_csv('C:\\myfilenew.csv', header=0, dtype={'CRM ID':str})
OLD_CRM = pd.read_csv('C:\\myfileold.csv', header=0, dtype={'NEW CRM ID':str})

Query1 = pd.merge(NEW_CRM, OLD_CRM, on='Known_Good_ID', how='left')

FinalTest = Query1.loc[Query1['CRM ID'.strip()] != Query1['NEW CRM ID'.strip()]]
```

The problem is, even with strip(), a blank value in CRM ID compared to a blank value in NEW CRM ID is being returned as not equal.  I'm not sure as to the best way to proceed as options include attempting to convert everything to numeric, or populating the blank strings etc.  I'd imagine there has to be a more elegant way to handle this.

Addition (Sample Data As Requested):

```
NEW_CRM:
Known_Good_Id, NEW CRM ID
100, 1005
101, 2003
102, abcd
103, 
104, 4008

OLD_CRM:
Known_Good_Id, CRM ID
100, 1005
101, 2003
102, 9878
103, 
104, 4002
107, 5005

Query1:
Known_Good_ID, NEW CRM ID, CRM ID
100, 1005, 1005
101, 2003, 2003
102, abcd, 9879
103,,
104, 4008, 4002

FinalTest Expected Result:
102, abcd, 9879
104, 4008, 4002

FinalTest Actual Result:
102, abcd, 9879
103,,
104, 4008, 4002
```

*I do not wish to return record 103 because of the blank strings

Comment: we cannot help you unless you provide real sample data

Comment: By "blank" values do you mean `NaN`? There shouldn't be an issue with the empty string.

Comment: Also `'NEW CRM ID'.strip()` just strips the whitespace from that string you wrote, not the values in the column. I think you instead want something like `Query1['NEW CRM ID'].str.strip()` which may solve your problem.